# Regex - Take all caracters after the last slash

Tags: regex, url

I have this:
http://server/service/local/repositories/domain/content/name/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/name2-1.0.0-20161114.174435-142.pom

I would like to take only **name2-1.0.0-20161114.174435-142.pom** using **Regex**

I tried something like `\/(.)*.pom$` but it selects all caracters starting with the two slashs.

Heeeelp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "http://server/service/local/repositories/domain/content/name/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/name2-1.0.0-20161114.174435-142.pom"|sed 's/^.*\/\([^/]*\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following expression:

```
[^\/]+\.pom$
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/dOg0yi/1

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Lookaround:

```
(?=name\w)\V+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u1o3yG/2

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex: `[^\/]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/Zn5n6e/1